# Excel VBA workseet change event not firing on data validation change

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I'm a bit rusty on VBA, but used to do this with no problem.

I have a worksheet change event written so that when I change the item from a data validation list in a cell, it recalculates the table. I've done this many times before but for some reason it is not even firing as a break point on the first line of code in the event macro does not even get hit when I change the value of the cell with the validation dropdown.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
Set wsData = Sheets("RackCosts")
Set wsTarget = ActiveSheet

Dim TargetRangeValue As Variant
Dim numUnits As Integer
Dim unitCost As Double
Dim numUnitsRange As Range, unitCostRange As Range
Set numUnitsRange = wsTarget.Range("NumUnits")
Set unitCostRange = wsTarget.Range("Cost_Unit")

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
'EquipType is the cells named range
If Target = wsTarget.Range("EquipType") Then
    TargetRangeValue = Target.Value
```

A breakpoint is not even hit in this event when the data validation cell is changed and the breakpoint is on the Set wsData = ... code line

Any help as to why this isn't even firing would be appreciated.

Note: I added enabling events in the workbook open event to ensure events were enabled (Yes, I know that is the default)....didn't help.

Note2: And yes, the code is in the proper worksheet.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `Set wsData = Sheets("RackCosts")` and commenting out the `On Error` line?

Comment: 1. Don'y use ActiveSheet in a worksheet_change; use `Set wsTarget = target.parent` instead. 2. Run `?application.enableevents = true` in the VBE's Immediate window. Does it trigger now?

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald...Yes I have

Comment: @Jeeped...events are enabled...?Application.EnableEvents = True
True...I also changed from ActiveSheet to Sheets("Sheetname")

Comment: @Jeeped Why even bother with `wsTarget` - you can just use `Me` instead to reference the Worksheet that the change event was in: `Set numUnitsRange = Me.Range("NumUnits")`

Comment: @Chronocidal - agreed! I was just trying to follow the op's vernacular while avoiding the problems inherit when target.parent is not the active worksheet.

Comment: @dinotom 2 minor things:  Try adding `Debug.Print "'" & Me.Name & "'!"; Target.Address(True, True, xlA1) & " = " & Target.Value` as the very first line in the Sub, before your first `Dim` and see what appears in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) when you change drop-downs and free-type in cells.  Finally, it's "safer" to explicitly use the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` collection instead of just the `Sheets` collection

Comment: @Chronocidal...tried that...nothing prints, whether I change that data validation item or even if i type in other cells on the sheet. Its as if no events are enabled, but they are. I am using Office 365, can that be the issue?

Comment: Setting `EnableEvents` to True in an event procedure doesn't help. Try `? Application.EnableEvents` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: @Variatus...See above comments. Did that...It is true

Comment: Try opening a new/fresh workbook, and set up the `Worksheet_Change` event with *just* the line of code I gave earlier.  **If** that works, **and** your workbook still doesn't, then there are 2 options:  1) You have code elsewhere in the WorkBook that is interrupting the Event or 2) Your WorkBook is corrupt, and you need to copy/paste all of the data and code into a new WorkBook.  Otherwise...  well, have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @Chronocidial...rebooted....works now...ridiculous that that is always the solution in windows